# js/jquery/html: getting a div from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I grab a div from an iframe into a JS variable?  Doesn't necessarily have to use jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('IframeId').contentWindow.document.getElementById('DivId');
```

Comment: Just remember that this (or any other method) won't work cross domain because of security restrictions

Answer (score 9):

In jQuery syntax, that would be `$('iframe').contents().find('div')`.  (Substitute any specific ids/classes/other selectors you need, of course).  Tracker1's answer should work fine for standard Javascript.

Comment: I prefer the jQuery approach myself... bear in mind, it breaks when going more than one iFrame deep (like in MS's SQL Reporting services, ugh).